# difference between "do tasks" inside an useEffect hook or before return render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, jsx

I'd like to know what is the difference between "do tasks" inside an useEffect hook or before return render ?

Assuming the Object {data} I am sending as a props is { number1: 2, number2: 3 } in both cases

like:

```
import React from "react";

export default ({ data }) => {
  let resultSum = 0;

  let number1 = data.number1;
  let number2 = data.number2;
  resultSum = number1 + number2;

  return <div>{resultSum}</div>;
};
```

or like that:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default ({ data }) => {
  const [resultSum, setResultSum] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let number1 = data.number1;
    let number2 = data.number2;
    setResultSum(number1 + number2);
  }, []);

  return <div>{resultSum}</div>;
};
```

In both cases page will render result as 5 and in both cases task will be processed before rendering page... What is the difference ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is that, in the first case, the first render of your component returns the value directly, and doesn't rerender by itself because there was no state change.

In the second case, there was a first initial render with the value of 0.

Do a `console.log` in the second case, right before the return, and you'll
notice it.

---

The `useEffect` callback is called after your component mounts, but after the first render. Although the effect you'll visually see is the same, you should consider using the `useEffect` method when you intend to do some initial processing as soon as the component is mounted, like, for example, fetching some data from an API.

In your case, as you only want to do some calculation based on props (your outputted result is based solely on props), you should consider returning it directly, so using the first method is best here, as your component is pure (only depends on props).